# firestore firebase storage retrieve image at lower resolution

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Is it possible to retrieve an image from firebase storage through firestore at a lower resolution?

I have my website design where it display multiple pictures at a small size. And when click on it, it shows that picture at full screen. So I want  **some feature** so it loads all the images at lower res.. and then when click.. it loads at full res.

```
  private readonly imagesCol = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('IMAGES')


  getImages() {
    return this.imagesCol .get();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use install the firestore `Resize Images` extension:

https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images

The source code is also available, so you can opt to customize this as a cloud function.